# No value for argument 'score' in unbound method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to create a class as follows:

```
class Student:
    numberOfStudents = 0
    numberofsections = 0

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to our humble organization.")

    def RegisterStudent(self, name, age, phonenumber, score):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number = phonenumber
        self.score = score
        Student.numberOfStudents += 1
        return "Registeration is done successfully"

    def ViewStudentData(self):
        return f"Student name: {self.name}\nStudent age: {self.age}\nStudent score: {self.score}"

    @classmethod
    def Number_Of_Students(cls):
        return f"The number of students is: {Student.numberOfStudents}"

    @classmethod
    def Number_Of_Sections(cls):
        Student.numberofsections = (Student.numberOfStudents/30)
        Student.numberofsections = int(Student.numberofsections)
        return f"Numebr of sections is {Student.numberofsections}"

    @classmethod
    def View_year_Data(cls):
        return Student.Number_Of_Students(), Student.Number_Of_Sections()
```

And when I tried to call an instance method as follows:

```
Std_One = Student.RegisterStudent("Yakoza", 21, "5465164641564", 80)
```

It gives me this error:

```
No value for argument 'score' in unbound method call pylint(no-value-for-parameter)
```

Where is the error, I can't see it (In Dora's voice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling it as `Student.RegisterStudent(...)`, you're using `RegisterStudent` as a classmethod, even though you want to create an instance of the `Student`. The easy fix is:

```
StdOne = Student().RegisterStudent("Yakoza", 21, "5465164641564", 80)
```

That `Student()` part creates an *instance* of your class, which is then passed to `RegisterStudent` as the variable `self`. (You were getting the error because in your original call, `self="Yakoza"`, `name=21`, `age="5465164641564"` and `phonenumber=80`; so `score` was not getting a value. The underlying reason is the way it was called.)

However, `RegisterStudent` returns the text 'Registeration is done successfully', which is not useful to store in the variable. Change the return line to `return self`, the object which was created by the call to `Student()`.

```
def RegisterStudent(self, name, age, phonenumber, score):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.number = phonenumber
    self.score = score
    Student.numberOfStudents += 1
    print("Registeration is done successfully")
    return self
```

After that, you can see that it works by:

```
>>> print(StdOne.name)
'Yakoza'
>>> print(Student.numberOfStudents)
1
```

---

Btw, you should initialise all the instance variables in `__init__()`, even if just to set them to `None`, since Python3 optimizes the instance dictionaries ***if*** the instance variables are all declared in `__init__()`. So:

```
class Student:
    numberOfStudents = 0
    numberofsections = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.age = None
        self.number = None
        self.score = None
        print("Welcome to our humble organization.")
```

Comment: I don't know what to say, I'm very thankful and grateful for you man, not just for the answer, but for the additional tip ❤❤❤

Comment: You can use `RegisterStudent` as a classmethod, like you've done for the others: Change `self` to `cls` and inside it, you can do `inst = cls()` which will create an instance of `Student` and then do `inst.name = ...` etc. followed by `return inst`. And then call it like you did originally.